# Migrating from Python 2.7 to 3.7 - difference between isinstance(obj, None) vs is None

Tags: python

I have to migrate a project from Python 2.7 to 3.7.

This line of code used to work in 2.7

```
if isinstance(obj, None):
```

for some reason it doesn't anymore. If I modify it this way:

```
if isinstance(obj, type(None)):
```

it will work though.

But my question is, what is the difference between this call:

```
isinstance(obj, None)
```

and

```
obj is None
```

why did the original devs decided to use isinstance over is? (in py 2.7)

Thanks.

Comment: In both versions the preferred way to check for `None` is `obj is None`. I can not tell you why the devs did that complicated comparison.

Comment: I'm kinda amazed `if isinstance(obj, None):` ever worked; `None` is not an instance of `None` (`None` is not a class, nothing is an instance of it).

Comment: It certainly doesn't work in Python 2.7.16.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation hints at `None` being silently promoted to `type(None)` (similar to what is allowed in type hints), either.

Comment: @chepner: In that case, I'm confused as to where the OP saw it working at all.

Comment: It was used in Django 1.11 with python 2.7. After upgrading to py 3.7, I get an error pointing at that line.

Comment: Is it possible the line has never been executed, or that the resulting `TypeError` has been swallowed by a `try` statement that suppressed it unintentionally?

Comment: There is a possibility (it is slim though) that the line was never executed, but there was no try statement for sure. Are you sure it couldn't work though?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: Nothing in the language spec would allow it to work, and the last releases of 2.7 definitely don't work (as chepner verified), so *if* it ever worked, it was a bug in the Python interpreter you were using. [The `isinstance` docs in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) are quite clear: "If `classinfo` is not a class, type, or tuple of classes, types, and such tuples, a `TypeError` exception is raised." `None` is not a class, not a type, and not a `tuple`, so the spec requires it to raise `TypeError` if you try to do what you show.

Comment: "This line of code used to work in 2.7" It did not, and the behaviour of `isinstance` is not different from 2.7 to 3.7, nor is it different between 3.x versions [until 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). Voting to close as not reproducible. FWIW, `obj is None` is the canonical way to perform this check. Also, nobody here can possibly tell you why the devs of the code you're working on chose to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` operator is used to check if both the objects are one and the same, whereas `isinstance` is used to check if the second parameter appears anywhere in the inheritance chain of the first parameter.

```
obj is None
```

`obj` is actually `None`.

```
isinstance(obj, type(None))
```

Check `obj` is None type object.

But actually there is only one object of None type. None is the only object of the None Type. So when you specify None type, you write it as `type(None)`.

After all, `isinstance(None, type(None))` is true.

Comment: In Python 3.10 they added a [`types.NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.NoneType) that could also be used with `isinstance()`.

Comment: @martineau: Mind you, they made `types.NoneType` the same way you did it pre-3.10, [with `NoneType = type(None)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/types.py#L304). It's incredibly unusual to actually need access to `NoneType`, and easy enough to generate if you really need it, which is why they didn't bother to expose it directly for so long (I'm guessing they added it basically for consistency with the other singletons they exposed the types of, largely for type hinting purposes, even though `None` was special-cased not to need `NoneType` for type hinting).